# После закрытия Xib-вьюшки область которая была ею закрыта не активна

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib

После закрытия Xib-вьюшки область которая была ею закрыта не активна, те кнопки не реагируют на нажатия, будто вьюшка осталась сверху, просто прозрачная

файл к Xib

```
import UIKit

class View: UIView {
var view = UIView()

@IBOutlet weak var exersiseName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
super.init(frame: frame)
setup()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
setup()
}
func setup() {
  view = loadViewFromNib()
  view.frame = bounds
view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
addSubview(view)

}
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

let bundle = NSBundle(forClass:self.dynamicType)
let nib = UINib(nibName: "View", bundle: bundle)
let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

return view
}
```

активация вьюшки

```
var mySubview: View!
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton){

  if(mySubview != nil && !mySubview.view.hidden) {
     mySubview.view.removeFromSuperview()
  }
  mySubview = View(frame: CGRect  (x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250))
  mySubview.exersiseName.text = "Exersise"

  mySubview.cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  mySubview.cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: "myCancelButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
  mySubview.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y)
  self.view.addSubview(mySubview)
}

func myCancelButtonTapped(sender:UIButton) {
   mySubview.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mySubview.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Вы удаляете вьюшку из своей subView.
Замените на

```
 mySubview.removeFromSuperview()
```